# tableview image to be display in detailview

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, ios-simulator

DetailsViewController.h

```
{
 UIImageView *Image;
}

@property(retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* Image;
```

DetailsViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 self.Title.text = location.title;
 self.desc.text = location.description;
```

this is the code to pull data from plist whenever user select a row in the uitableview..so the problem i am having now is how should i do it if i wan it to display an image?can't seems to get it after a few attempts..greatly appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for just the way to display an image, it is simple.

on Interface Builder,

1. make Image View
2. make connection between 1 and Outlet
3. set the image path (short cut : Command + 1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load this image into a UIImageView as suggested by cappucino, setup an IBOutlet like this so you have something to connect it to.

```
// in your header (.h) file in the interface definition
IBOutlet UIImageView *myIBImage;

// and at the bottom with your property declarations
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *myIBImage;
```

Also synthesize it at the top of you implementation file (.m)

```
@synthesize myIBImage;
```

Then in Interface Builder make the connections like this http://vimeo.com/3780487

Once connected, you can load the image into memory and set it to the view for your UIImageView.

```
// load an image from the bundle's path into memory
NSString* tmpStr = @"/myImage.png";
[myIBImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tmpStr]];
```

That's it. Who said iPhone coding is hard?
(Yes it is tricky, but you'll do it so often you'll hardly notice!) :D